# "Could not retrieve the specified page. Please verify correct href was passed in."

Tags: php, facebook-likebox

I'm getting the following error when trying to add the facebook like box on my website:

Could not retrieve the specified page. Please verify correct href was passed in.

The like box appears to work fine in my DEV folder that's a subdirectory within the public_html directory. So DEV/index.php worksfine when I have the data-herf contains "/DEV/". However, when I change the data-href to anything other than /DEV/, it fails.

Comment: Define anything other than dev.

Comment: Sounds like it's more of a hosting issue than a facebook like social plugin issue.  Can you get to that same URL if you type it into a browser?  Can you share the url that works and the one that doesnt?

Comment: Exact same problem here. Actually, it worked for, like 15 minutes, and then that message. Very mysterious. data-href is a full URL, tried to wget it and no problem. Facebook debug says everything is ok. But then, that message in the likebox ..

Answer (score 1):

data-href should be a **full** non-private URL like **http://www.stackoverflow.com**.
Don't use relative paths like **/foo/bar.php**.

Hope it helps!